# Symfony2 PDOSessionHandler Allows me to view one page, then kicks me out

Tags: session, symfony, pdo, doctrine

I'm trying to implement PDOSessionHandler for my Symfony2 setup.

It allows me to log in and takes me to the first page. But then when I try to navigate anywhere else, it takes me back to the log in page.

I know I'm not trying to jump firewalls or anything, because it works perfectly fine with the default session (session in a file). I've created the session table and it writes the sessions. When I log back in, it keeps the same session ID even, but it still won't let me get past the first page.

I've also made sure the server time is set correctly. My database is running on my web server in this environment and I've verified they are both using the correct time.

The table looks like this (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `session_value` text NOT NULL,
  `session_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_id_UNIQUE` (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I am using the following configs:

```
framework:
  session:
    handler_id: session.handler.pdo

parameters:
  pdo.db_options:
    db_table:    session
    db_id_col:   session_id
    db_data_col: session_value
    db_time_col: session_time

services:
  pdo:
    class: PDO
    arguments:
      - "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
      - "%database_user%"
      - "%database_password%"
  session.handler.pdo:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    arguments: ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%"]
```

I'm using the latest version of Symfony as well (2.3).

I do a few things with the token as well and have a custom authentication provider, but don't do anything that should be invalidating the session itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

Update:

I just noticed that on the session, it always keeps my _security.firewall.target_path attribute, but seems to lose the _security_firewall property ("firewall" is actually the name of the specific firewall in play). Hope that gives someone an idea.

Comment: debug $session->isStarted() in your other controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks highly likely that I'm suffering from a sort of "race" condition. It looks like there is an official Symfony bug tracking this, though it seems to be proving rather elusive to pin down exactly.

[Symfony Bug Tracker Issue 6417](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6417#issuecomment-19206373)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your session is started correctly in your other action which redirects you to the login.

```
$this->container->get('session')->isStarted()
```

Doesn't sound like the sesion is invalidated if you receive the same session id when logging in again.

Comment: I can add that tomorrow when I get to the office to check. However, it isn't just one page, it seems to be every possible page I can go to. And if I simply comment out the handler_id line (and log back in) everything works as intended, so I don't think it's anything funny that I'm doing with the sessions.

Comment: I gave this a shot. I put this at the top of the controller for the page I could get to and it says it is started. I even tried starting it in a Kernel REQUEST event and it didn't change the behavior. I did notice that the session it gives me while on the page is the same it says I have when I'm redirected to the login. Also, the log tells me " Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.)" Any more ideas? Thanks.